# Property of set of zero Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Does there exist $A\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ whose Lebesgue measure is zero but contains a non measurable subset? Here the sigma algebra is $\mathcal{L}\times\mathcal{L}$ where $\mathcal{L}$ is the set of all Lebesgue measurable set in $\mathbb{R}.$

Surely this property does not hold true in one dimension.

Comment: To define non-measurable sets you need to specify a $\sigma-$algebra. If your $\sigma$-algebra is the Lebesgue sigma-algebra then it is not true. But if you have a different sigma-algebra, of course, it can happen.

Comment: The sigma algebra is $\mathcal{L}\times\mathcal{L}$ where $\mathcal{L}$ is the set of all Lebesgue measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: I guess $\mathcal{L}\times\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{L}^2, $ where $\mathcal{L}^2$ is the set of all Lebesgue measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}^2.$

Comment: No, actually $\mathcal{L}\times\mathcal{L}\neq \mathcal{L}^2.$

Comment: To see this take $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ to be a non-measurable subset. Now $A\times\{0\}$ has outer measure zero and therefore is $\mathcal{L}^2$ measurable (Recall that Lebesgue sigma-algebra is complete). Convince yourself that $A\times\{0\}$ is not $\mathcal{L}\times\mathcal{L}$ measurable. (Look at the slices of $A\times\{0\}.$)

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Comment: So I guess $ [0,1]\times \{0\}$ will serve our purpose. Please comment

Comment: Exactly! Any set of the form $A\times \{0\}$ will do your job,  $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ has positive (1-dimensional) Lebesgue measure.